# Container DIV is not stretching beyond original height of window

Tags: css, height

I am using the following CSS for a container DIV with height of html and body set to 100%, and yet it is not stretching beyond the edge of the window on [this page](http://salliannputman.com/test/index.html), i.e. when scrolling up to reveal content lower down the page, the container DIV is not showing:

```
#container {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  background-color: #292929;
  width: 1200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  min-height: 100%;
}
```

Could someone please let me know why this isn't working.

Comment: You either need to add a `clear: both` element to the bottom of `#content`, or add `overflow: auto;` to the `#container` style block. (Note, you could add `overflow: auto` to `.container`, but you'd have to deal with a scrollbar; also, the `#container` fixes aren't perfect either, as the `float: right` box doesn't expand the `#content` below it's bottom.)

Comment: @JaredFarrish, you should make that an answer.

Comment: Actually, adding `overflow: hidden` to the `#container` style definition fixes the issue.

Comment: @FakeRainBrigand - I hadn't quite gotten it worked out yet. `:)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add `overflow: hidden` to:

```
#container {
    overflow: hidden; /* Right here */
    background-color: #292929;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-top: 0;
    min-height: 100%;
    padding-bottom: 0;
    padding-left: 0;
    padding-right: 0;
    padding-top: 0;
    width: 1200px;
}
```

That will cause `#container` to flow past the bottom of the floated elements within it that should give it it's calculated height. Another option is to do a [`.clearfix`](http://www.positioniseverything.net/easyclearing.html).

Comment: Thanks, that fixes the issue with the container.  For some reason the sidebar is now getting cut off at the bottom though.  Probably unrelated to your answer, but if you have any clues as to why this is happening I'd be glad to hear them!

Comment: You can add `padding-bottom` definitions to `#container` and `#sidebar`. It looks like `35px` and `20px` respectively will work out good.

Comment: Thanks again Jared.  That works fine.  Enjoy your day/evening.

Answer (score -2):

You should use Height, instead of width:

```
height: 1200px;
```

Instead of:

```
width: 1200px;
```

Comment: I don't know where you're getting this idea from, but that's not what the problem is.

Comment: i dont think thats what he is looking for